# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nullable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I'm getting below error in my server startup logs. Tried adding dependency `jsr305` from `com.google.code.findbugs` but still seeing same exceptions.Any help will be appreciated.

This issue i'm facing after upgrading my mongo java driver version to 3.2.2, spring-data-mongodb to 1.9.4.RELEASE, spring-data-commons to 1.12.1 and Spring framework version to 4.2.8.RELEASE.

```
06:37:33.943 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nullable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:976) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:695) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:121) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate$LenientAssignableTypeFilter.match(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:202) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:346) [spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:280) [spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.multipleStoresDetected(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:167) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.<init>(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:88) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:80) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to really tell what is going on, but here are some pointers to investigate:

The exception means

1. The class in question is not loaded at all, or
2. not loaded by the classloader you are currently using.

There are many points where the class (or the jar it is contained in can get lost):

1. Assuming you are using Gradle, Maven or similar, print out the dependency tree to ensure, the jar is actually included.
2. Open up the jar with a unzip to to verify the class is actually present
3. Print out the classpath at runtime https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html to verify the jar is included in there (it probably isn't)
4. Use a debugger to find out what classloader is actually trying to find the class and check what classpath it is using, do the same for the parent classloaders

In my experience with these steps you most likely will be able to identify your root problem and fix it. If not come back with the information you got and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I update to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```